# Is this simple proof that the Frobenius endomorphism of an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb F_q$ is surjective valid?

Tags: proof-verification, elliptic-curves

I am quite sure that the following "proof" is flawed, but I don't see why:

> Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb F_q$. Since $E$'s ideal is generated by a polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[X]$, it is left invariant by the Frobenius endomorphism
>   $$\varphi\colon\;E\to E,\;(x,y)\mapsto(x^q,y^q) \text.$$
>   Hence, the image of $E$ under $\varphi$ is the curve whose ideal is $E$'s ideal, that is $\varphi(E)=E$, thus $\varphi$ is a surjection.

Is this reasoning valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the curve $X+Y=0$ defined over $k = \Bbb F_2(Z)$. The point $(Z,Z)$ of the curve is not in the image of $\phi$ even though the ideals of the curve and of its image by $\phi$ are the same.

Comment: I was asking specifically about $k=\mathbb F_q$, and my definition of $E$ only includes points from an algebraic closure of $k$. Do I miss something?

Comment: well then $E(\Bbb F_q)$ is finite and $\phi$ is injective, so ...

Comment: Oh, now I see, your answer wasn't supposed to be a counterexample for my whole statement (which is clearly true) but for the last implication. Thank you!